# How to detect when button pressed and released on android

Tags: java, android, button, timer, pressed

I would like to start a timer that begins when a button is first pressed and ends when it is released (basically I want to measure how long a button is held down). I'll be using the System.nanoTime() method at both of those times, then subtract the initial number from the final one to get a measurement for the time elapsed while the button was held down.

(If you have any suggestions for using something other than nanoTime() or some other way of measuring how long a button is held down, I'm open to those as well.)

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: Similar to this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410362/2069407

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) instead of OnClickListener:

```
// this goes somewhere in your class:
  long lastDown;
  long lastDuration;

  ...

  // this goes wherever you setup your button listener:
  button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
        }

        return true;
     }
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when the button is pressed with the keyboard. It only works when it is touched.

Comment: So you are wanting to see how long a keyboard button is pressed?

Comment: This aproach needs to be modifed. If you press then slide your finger holding the button in a press state then release the finger the button stays pressed. You need also add `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` to handle that kind of behaviour.

Comment: also missing `return true` at the end of `onTouch` method

Answer (score 7):

This will definitely work:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            increaseSize();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            resetSize();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

1. In onTouchListener start the timer.
2. In onClickListener stop the times.

calculate the differece.