# How to select GridView item and use onTouchListener in getView?(they seem to cancel each other out)

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview

When i use an onTouchListener in the getView of my adapter the line

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/circle"
```

immediately stops working, if I set onTouch to return false it works again, however then the ACTION_DOWN ACTION_UP dosent work properly.

Heres what i have in onTouch

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Assets.playMusic(songID, false);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {              
                Assets.mediaPlayer.stop();
                Assets.mediaPlayer = null;
                }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Its suppose to play music for as long as you have a finger held on the item and when you release it should stop the music.  And it works well when returning true. However for some reason the circle stops appearing behind the tapped items.  If it is set to false the circle appears, but then action_up dosent stop the music

ive tried using .setSelected .setActivated .setEnabled and none of them work
please help

Also i want it to work kinda like snapchats camera button, tap it and it does one thing, hold it and it does something for duration of your hold.  I was going to use time variables in the Action up and down. but if anyone knows another way to do this id appreciate info about that too

Comment: you should use gridview.setOnItemClickListener instead

Comment: I need to be able to detect how long it is held and when it is released. onItemClick cant do that?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation is not encouraged to attach an OnTouchListener to the image, but to the items of the GridView instead.

You should have something like this:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.the_gridview_id);
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View v, int position, long id) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:
In order to know how much time a view is pressed, you can do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964082/2823516):

```
// this goes somewhere in your class:
long lastDown;
long lastDuration;

...


// this goes wherever you setup your button listener:
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         lastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
      } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
         lastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDown;
      }
   }
};
```

Comment: I need to be able to detect how long it is held and when it is released. onItemClick cant do that?

Comment: shouldnt there be a method to call on a view that says "hey select this item in the gridView"

Comment: isnt that exactly what i did? it dosent work as soon as you attach the onTouchListener.  android:listSelector="@drawable/circle" stops working it stops selecting

Comment: we need a way to figure out what triggers listSelector

Comment: Is not the same. Try to do it programatically instead via XML