# How to separate Button Longpress Button press Up and Down events

Tags: java, android, button, long-press

I have a Click function and long press on the same button. Implemented the long press event but, I need to find the button UP_EVENT and DOWN_EVENTS separately.
How can I implement by using the `OnLongClickListener`

```
 View.OnLongClickListener listener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                return true;
            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implement a TouchListener within the onLongClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963763/how-to-detect-when-button-pressed-and-released-on-android):

```
    View.OnLongClickListener listener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            // PRESSED
                            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // RELEASED
                            return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` events you need to implement `OnTouchListener`.

Answer (score 0):

to sepate , you can do this way

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (isOnClick) {                    
                //TODO onClick code
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```