# how to get duration of pressed button before release it?

Tags: android, android-button, android-event

I want to calculate duration of when `Action_Down` button before `Action_Up` in `onTouchListener`

Can I get how long my button was pressed? And doing something when timeout reaches to my desire value?

For example, i want to make a customize `onLongClickListener` with different timeout.

**Edited**

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324362/detect-touch-press-vs-long-press-vs-movement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410362/how-to-detect-the-period-for-which-a-button-is-press-in-android) is also like as this question but not is answer for this question. In these all used by Action_Up of `onTouchListener` that not are answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You should override [OnTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) in your view, and if the event is [ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN), record the current time by creating a new instance of Date. When you receive ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL, create another instance of date and subtract the first value to get the difference in time.

Comment: No buddy, you didn't read my question fully. I want calculate it before touch event equal to action_up

Comment: In that case you can post a delayed runnable when ACTION_DOWN is received, please clarify your question